# How does one tell Ninject to treat any Class<T> as a singleton

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

So here's what I got:

Two repositories: `CreditCardRepository` and `DepartmentRepository`

Then I have a `EntitySignal<T>` that looks something like this:

```
public interface EntitySignal<T>
{
    event Action<T> Created;
    event Action<T> Removed;
    event Action<T> Updated;
}
```

And I'd just inject one or more of these signals into my repository constructors... for example, `CreditCardRepository` deals with CreditCards and Transactions, so I would want signals for both of those.

Now my big question is if there is an easy way to tell Ninject for any `EntitySignal<T>`, make it a singleton. For example, I could do something like this with a regular interface:

`Bind<IMyContract>().To<ContractImplementation>().InSingletonScope()`

How could I do something like that with `EntitySignal<T>`, but for any type T? Is it possible?

Something like this...

```
Bind<EntitySignal<CreditCard>>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
Bind<EntitySignal<Transaction>>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
Bind<EntitySignal<Department>>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
Bind<EntitySignal<TrafficReport>>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

And it could be even further done like this...

```
Bind<IDepartment>().To<BransonDepartment>();
Bind<EntitySignal<IDepartment>>.ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: So you want a single instance that references both `EntitySignal<CreditCard>` and `EntitySignal<Transaction>` classes? Can you show me an example of how you would do this manually in code?

Comment: I added a bit to the bottom, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bind(typeof(EntitySignal<>))
    .ToSelf()
    .InSingletonScope()
```